Norm Equality for Slice Maps of C*-Algebras
I am reading a paper on $C^{*}$-algebras, and one of the techniques employed several times is the concept of a slice map.  In particular, if $A,B$ are $C^{*}$-algebras and $\varphi \in A^{*}$, we can define the map $S_{\varphi}: A \odot B \longrightarrow B$ by $S_f(a \otimes b) = \varphi(a)b$.
Now, $S_{\varphi}$ has a bounded extension (to the minimal tensor product) with $\lVert S_{\varphi} \rVert \leq \lVert \varphi \rVert$.  To see this, observe that: $$\left\lVert S_{\varphi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \otimes b_k\right) \right\rVert = \left\lVert \sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(a_k)b_k \right\rVert = \sup_{\lVert \psi \rVert \leq 1} \left|\psi\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(a_k)b_k \right) \right|$$ $$= \sup_{\lVert \psi \rVert \leq 1} \left|(\varphi \otimes \psi)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \otimes b_k \right) \right| \leq \sup_{\lVert \psi \rVert \leq 1} \lVert \varphi \otimes \psi \rVert \left\lVert \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \otimes b_k \right\rVert$$ $$= \lVert \varphi \rVert \left\lVert \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \otimes b_k \right\rVert.$$  However, the paper claims that $\lVert S_{\varphi} \rVert = \lVert \varphi \rVert$, and it says this follows from the 'usual Von-Nuemann algebra techniques'.  I however only study $C^{*}$-algebras in my graduate program and I am just starting to learn VNA theory, so I am unsure of what 'the usual' / 'the standard' techniques are to show this equality.
If someone could write it out (with my background in mind please!) that'd be fantstic!

If I have to make a guess, I’d assume the authors meant the fact that, for any $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, its double dual $A^{\ast\ast}$ has a natural vNa structure that makes the canonical inclusion $A \subset A^{\ast\ast}$ an embedding of $C^\ast$-algebras in which $A$ is weakly dense in $A^{\ast\ast}$. Then $A \otimes B$ is naturally a weakly dense $C^\ast$-subalgebra of the vNa $A^{\ast\ast} \mathbin{\overline{\otimes}} B^{\ast\ast}$, and $S_\varphi$ naturally extends to a $\sigma$-weakly continuous map $\tilde{S}_\varphi: A^{\ast\ast} \mathbin{\overline{\otimes}} B^{\ast\ast} \to B^{\ast\ast}$. Then there is a norm-achieving element $a \in A^{\ast\ast}$ for $\varphi$, i.e., $\|a\| = 1$ and $\varphi(a) = \|\varphi\|$, so $\tilde{S}_\varphi(a \otimes 1) = \varphi(a)1 = \|\varphi\|1$ and thus $\|S_\varphi\| = \|\tilde{S}_\varphi\| \geq \|\varphi\|$.
Now, if this is actually what the authors meant, I have two objections. The first is that I don’t think double duals really count as “usual vNa techniques”, since they are rarely used in vNa theory. The second is that this proof is vastly over-complicated. Indeed, while $A$ may not have a norm-achieving element for $\varphi$, it will have approximately norm-achieving ones. That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $a \in A$ with $\|a\| = 1$ and $|\varphi(a)| \geq (1 - \epsilon)\|\varphi\|$. Now, pick any $b \in B$ of norm $1$, then,
$$\|S_\varphi\| \geq \|S_\varphi(a \otimes b)\| = |\varphi(a)|\|b\| \geq (1 - \epsilon)\|\varphi\|$$
Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ yields the desired result.
